# Android volley How to send request with both authentification headers and Json object in body

Tags: android, json, android-volley

I need to send via volley a http request with both authentification header and Json object in body. Bu I did not found a request for this in volley.

I found GsonRequest  and JsonObjectRequest.
**GsonRequest**
int method, String url, Class clazz, Map **headers**, Listener listener, ErrorListener errorListener, Gson useGson)

**JsonObjectRequest**
(int method, java.lang.String url, JSONObject **jsonRequest**, Response.Listener listener, Response.ErrorListener errorListener)

Any idea what to do ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your Request class, override `getHeaders()` to send custom Headers

> To send parameters in request body you need to override either
>   getParams() or getBody() method of the request classes

described here:

[Asynchronous HTTP Requests in Android Using Volley](http://arnab.ch/blog/2013/08/asynchronous-http-requests-in-android-using-volley/)

Comment: I have tried, but it doesn't work as JsonObjectRequest get the body content directly.

Answer (score 1):

try this code

```
@Override
public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
    HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
    String creds = String.format("%s:%s","USERNAME","PASSWORD");
    String auth = "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString(creds.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
    params.put("Authorization", auth);
    return params;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Both getHeaders() and getParams() methods can be used simultaneously for sending data separately as header and body.

```
JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new 
                    JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
                    url,
                    null,
                    new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                            Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                        }
                    },
                    new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            Log.d(TAG, error.toString());
                        }
                    }) {
                @Override
                public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                    HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();

                    headers.put(headerKey, headerValue);
                    return headers;
                }

                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                    params.put(bodyKey, bodyValue);
                    return params;
                }
            };
            VolleySingleton.getInstance(getActivity()).addToRequestQueue(jsonObjectRequest);
```

This worked for me!!

Comment: getParams is only called for POST requests. GET requests don't have a body and hence, getParams is never called.