# BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 500 for Volley

Tags: android, android-volley

i am trying to create a user login page, i am getting this error while i try to register.I guess there is a problem with the Json object part.I tried searching for other answers in the forum but none of seem to address my problem. Request you to help me out with this. Thanks is advance.

```
 public void registercheck(final String name, final String email, final String password) {
    String tag_req = "Register_request";
    pdialog.setMessage("Registering ...");
    showDialog();

    StringRequest strR = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, Appconfig.LOGIN_URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String s) {
            hidedialog();
            try {
                JSONObject jsp = new JSONObject(s);
                boolean error = jsp.getBoolean("error");
                if (!error) {
                    String uid = jsp.getString("uid");
                    JSONObject user = jsp.getJSONObject("user");
                    String name = user.getString("name");
                    String email = user.getString("email");
                    String created_at = user.getString("created_at");
                    db.addUser(name, email, uid, created_at);

                    session.setLogin(true);

                    Intent i = new Intent(Register.this, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    finish();

                } else {
                    String error_msg = jsp.getString("error_msg");
                    Toast.makeText(Register.this, error_msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }


            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
            Log.e(TAG, volleyError.getMessage());
        }
    }) {

            @Override
        public Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> p = new HashMap<String, String>();
            p.put("name", name);
            p.put("tag", "register");
            p.put("email", email);
            p.put("password", password);

            return p;
```

My Log cat

```
15.407  11021-11440/example.com.login E/Volley﹕ [2407] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 500 for http://busappandroid.gear.host/
```

Comment: log the `request` object and `response` and show the request method signature for details

Comment: in your code you have not closed the string request or either the code you pasted has some thing left please check and correct as methods are not properly closed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add header Content-Type - text/html. I tried to call your api from postman rest client without headers it will give error 500  after adding header to api got result 200 status ok

Comment: Hi Ajinkya, Can you elaborate as to where should i add the Content Type .

Comment: In your Request class, override getHeaders() to send custom Headers you override getParams method same as that of you have getHeaders() method to overirde here is link that will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19962590/android-volley-how-to-send-request-with-both-authentification-headers-and-json-o

Comment: Hi I used the header as to get headers and content type, but it is overriding the getparams and is giving tag missing error. Where sholuld i place the header code.

Comment: if you are getting tag missing error means you get response from server

Answer (score 0):

`myReq.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(10000, 0, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));`

Add this line before addidng your request in volley.

This is the minimum number of retries. Default is 1, `DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT`.