# Upload image to server c# android

Tags: android

Well this might sound a question that has been asked few often times but I could not come with a solution for the same.I want to upload image to server C#, i got codes for how to send image but don't know exactly how to use it. Please correct my code if there is something wrong and any idea about server side code for the same correction.

```
     ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(AddPropertyThird.this);
                    progressDialog.setMessage("Uploading, please wait...");
                    progressDialog.show();

                    //converting image to base64 string
                    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
                    byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
                    final String imageString = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes,Base64.DEFAULT);

                    //sending image to server
                    StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String s) {
                            progressDialog.dismiss();

                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                            Toast.makeText(AddPropertyThird.this, "Some error occurred -> " + volleyError, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        }
                    }) {
                        //adding parameters to send
                        @Override
                        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                            Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<String, String>();
                            parameters.put("imageFile", imageString);
                            return parameters;
                        }
                    };

                    RequestQueue rQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(AddPropertyThird.this);
                    rQueue.add(request);
                }
            });
}
```

Logcat error

```
[879] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 500
02-09 12:33:24.106 2 E/volleyerror: com.android.volley.ServerError
```

Comment: What is your server receiving? Anything?

Comment: It is not receiving anything. And the toast above prints volley server error when running the code.

Comment: Don't Toast the error. Use `Log.e` and please edit your question with that logcat

Comment: i did @cricket_007

Comment: Did you look up what HTTP 500 error means?

Comment: @user1111 check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35029740/5180017) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28136202/5180017) StackOverflow threads

Comment: @cricket_007 yes i did but i have also used correct code for server side. So i thought there might be some problem with my working

Comment: @Shashanth okay i will check

Comment: Your server should have some logs that say exactly where the error occurred there.