# Getting error when trying to upload data to server

Tags: android, android-volley

I have been trying to upload my data from android to my server using java, volley and laravel but I am getting. BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 500. I have used postman to test my api and it is working perfectly well. 
What could be the cause?

Java code

```
  RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);  // this = context
    StringRequest postRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>()
            {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    // response

                    pd.dismiss();
                    Log.i("error", String.valueOf( response.toString()));

                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    // error
                    Toast.makeText(SignUpActivity.this, "Network Error. Please Try Again.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();;
                }
            }
    ) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams()
        {
            Map<String, String>  parameters = new HashMap<String, String>();
            parameters.put("email", email);
            parameters.put("password", password);
            parameters.put("vCode", vCode);
            parameters.put("phone",phone);
            return parameters;
        }
    };
    queue.add(postRequest);
```

Comment: might be duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/35029740/8311908

Comment: I have tried that but it did not work for me.

Comment: then coordinate with your backend team and ask them to fix it ....
there might be some issues from their end.

Answer (score 0):

Code 500 means that there's a problem at server side. If you're using laravel you should have a web server (as apache, nginx...) which generates error logs.

Check error logs and there you may find what the error is (maybe your app is sending data in a way that server doesn't understand, data is not being sent properly...).

[Apache error log location in Linux](https://blog.codeasite.com/how-do-i-find-apache-http-server-log-files/)

[Nginx error log location](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/admin/nginx/log_file/)

Comment: In case you don't have any of the web servers stated at my answer just write a comment and I will update it with information about that web server you're using